# Fatal error to Call to a member function fetch_assoc() - why is fetch_assoc() is not working?

Tags: php, mysql, json, android-studio, mysqli

Here is the error DbOperations. php codes:

```
public function getUserByUserid($user_id){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM mydb.User WHERE user_id = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
}
```

In another userLogin.php, i use the getUserByUserid($user_id) here:

```
if($db->userLogin($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['password'])){
    $user = $db->getUserByUserid($_POST['user_id']);
    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
    $response['name'] = $user['name'];
    $response['contact_no'] = $user['contact_no'];
    $response['email'] = $user['email'];
    $response['role'] = $user['role'];
```

And this is the error message:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Android\includes\DbOperations.php</b> on line
<b>41</b>
<br />
```

Line 41 is : `return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();`

Not sure what is the fetch_assoc() issue and i am a beginner...Thank you for helping:)

Comment: your real question (if you actually read the error message) should be `why does getResult() return a non-object` ?

Comment: I suppose before requesting any result query __must be executed__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **must** execute a query before trying to get results. Usually it is done with [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

```
public function getUserByUserid($user_id){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM mydb.User WHERE user_id = ?" );
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
    // Executing a query
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Going further you can check if your execution completed succesfully (`get_result()` returns **not** false in this case) and in case of error - somehow get error message with `mysqli_errno()` for example. More info (as **usual**) in a [manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php).